# Only return results if all rows that match 1st where clause also match the 2nd

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tables

```
Actions
----------
action_id

Tasks
---------
task_id
action_id
status_id  (can be: 1=waiting, 2=processing, 3=failed)
dt_created
```

I am trying to write a query that will return all 'actions' that:

*if have tasks created in the last 24 hours **all** have 'status' failed*

My difficulty is making sure there is not a task created in the last 24 hours that did not fail.

Thus a simple query fails as it will just return the results that match both.

```
select ....
WHERE tasks.dt_created > tasks.dt_created > now () - interval '1 day' AND
tasks.status_id=3
```

Am sure this is a simple query, but I must be searching using the wrong terminology as I find nothing

Comment: . . Sample data would help a lot.  All the negatives in the description are hard to follow.  For instance, do you want actions that have no tasks in the last 24 hours?  The "else" part of the logic is missing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, it seems I over simplified the issue. You assumed correct, I want all actions with no tasks and all actions with tasks created in last 24 hours that failed. I didn't put the above as I already have the query for "no tasks in last 24".

Comment: All 3 answers work: GordonLinoff, dasblinkenlight and Clodoaldo Neto. Am trying to find out which is "more right" before I mark an answer, whatever "more right means"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select action_id
from
    actions
    inner join
    tasks using(action_id)
where tasks.dt_created > now () - interval '1 day'
group by action_id
having bool_and(status_id = 3)
```

`bool_and` will evaluate to

> true if all input values are true, otherwise false

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html

This version using `bool_or` might be slightly faster

```
select action_id
from
    actions
    inner join
    tasks using(action_id)
where tasks.dt_created > now () - interval '1 day'
group by action_id
having not bool_or(status_id <> 3)
```

Comment: I am marking this as correct as I it taught me about the "bool_and" aggregate functions I didn't know about, and I think it is is the simplest, clearest way. This is what I was looking for, a way to say "return results if all true else fail"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the logic correctly, you want all actions older than one day.  Then you want newer actions where all the tasks are failed.  The following query implements this logic:

```
select action_id
from tasks t
group by action_id
having sum(case when t.dt_created < now () - interval '1 day' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
       sum(case when status_id <> 3 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Perhaps, though, you want the following:all actions that have tasks in the last 24 hours that did not fail:

```
select action_id
from tasks t
where t.dt_created >= now () - interval '1 day'
group by action_id
having sum(case when status_id <> 3 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: again, works, perfectly valid answer. Am new to case when then if so still trying to get my head round how this works, thus the "answer" went to bool_and.

Comment: @Martin The logic here is the same as in my answer, just, in my opinion, more verbose.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto . . . Your version has a totally unnecessary join to the `actions` table.